# DBXError at design-time while trying to connect to Oracle with Delphi XE7

Tags: oracle, delphi, 64-bit, dbexpress

I'm trying the new **Delphi XE7** and I'm trying to set a connection to **Oracle 12** (the client is 64 bit) with a `TSQLConnection`.

When I set property Connected to true I get a

> DBXError: Driver could not be properly initialized. Client library may be missing, not installed properly, of the wrong version, or the driver may be missing from the system path.

On Project Manager I set Target Platform to *64-bit Windows* and on menu **Project --> Options** I set Target to *All configuration - 64 bit Windows platform*.

With these settings the connection works at run time, but at design time I get the same error and I can't create fields.

What's wrong?

Comment: Delphi IDE is 32-bit.

Comment: Did you remember to install the Oracle Client on the local PC ? (OCI)

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/oci/index-090945.html

Comment: Yes, Oracle Client 64 bit is installed in the folder C:\app\client\product\12.1.0\client_1
The compiled program works, but not at design time.